# Rails: How to set up model´s attribute on initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, initialization

I am trying to set up an attribute of a model as soon as it is initialised. I have tried before_initialise, after_initialise, before_create, after_create.

What am I doing wrong?

```
describe "turn based system" do
  before(:each) do
    @user1 = Factory :user
    @user2 = Factory :user

    @rota = @user1.rotas.create
    @rota.users << @user2
  end

it "should be user1's turn at the beginning" do
  @rota.current_turn.should == @user1.id   --> fails
end
```

Implementation:

```
class Rota < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rotazations
  has_many :users, :through => :rotazations
  has_many :invitations

  after_create :set_current_turn

  private 

  def set_current_turn
    if self.users.count > 0
      self.current_turn = self.users[0].id
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**
If I construct the rota model using:

```
@rota = @user1.rotas.create(:current_turn => @user1.id)
```

it works - however, I feel like im duplicating code - I always want the current_turn field to be the object creator's id.

Thanks!

Comment: and for sure self.users.count > 0?

Comment: Im not quite sure - effectively when @user1.rotas.create - then for that particular rota the user count should be 1 (since its a many-to-many relation). However, maybe its not 1 when set_current_turn is called. How can I change the code so that the id of the user that creates the rota is set to current_turn

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: change `before_filter` to `after_create`

1) `before_filter` is the controller callback function.

2) You want to use `after_create` so the user has already been associated and you can use the association.

Comment: ive tried that too - unfortunately it didnt work. I think its because the object being initialized (rota instance) isnt aware of who created it (@user1 instance). So the method gets called, but rota.users = [] at that particular point

Comment: ok, do it `after_create` then, set the attribute and save right after. The user should be associated after that. (updated answer)

Comment: yeah, tried that too - users field still empty right after_create. What comes after after_create lol?

Comment: That should be the last one you need, weird, here is the full list if you want to try those: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html